# How to return result from event handler in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

How to return result from event handler in javafx? I have bellow code, and how to return data from event to function showPrompt? Is it possible to recover the data for the function of the event?

```
public static String showPrompt(String title, String defValue){
          final Stage dlgStage = new Stage();
          TextField txtPromptValue = new TextField(defValue);

          Button btnOk = new Button("Ok");
          Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
          btnOk.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
              @Override
              public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  //How to return data from event to function?
                  dlgStage.close();
              }
          });
          btnCancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
              @Override
              public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) { 
                  //How to return data from event to function?
                  dlgStage.close();
              }
          });
          //
          Label lblTitle = new Label(title);
          lblTitle.setFont(Font.font("Amble CN", FontWeight.NORMAL, 14));
          //
          VBox vbox = new VBox(lblTitle,txtPromptValue,btnOk,btnCancel);
          vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
          vbox.setMinSize(300, 200);
          //
          Scene dlgScene = new Scene(vbox);
          //
          dlgStage.setScene(dlgScene);
          dlgStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
          dlgStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
          dlgStage.setMinWidth(300);
          dlgStage.setMinHeight(200);
          dlgStage.show();
```

}

Comment: You want to execute some code from `showPrompt` when the event fires ? Please be more clear on what you mean by *return data from event to function*

Comment: For example, i want return for function showPrompt value "This is button Ok", or "This is button Cancel"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is you can't return a value.

#### Why ?

This code bellow is called a `callback`.

```
new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        dlgStage.close();
    }
}
```

Callbacks have no return type, as you can see in the example above, it is `void`.

Callbacks are *methods* that you pass as an *argument* to another method. The other method will call you *callback method* when it wants. This means that *callbacks* are asynchronous.
 In your example, it calls the *callback* when you press the button.

In conclusion, you can't return from it using `return`.

#### What to do ?

You can call a method from your *callback* and sent your `return` value to it as an *argument*.

Example:

```
btnCancel.setOnAction(
   new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            YourClass.setReturnValue("This is button Cancel");
            dlgStage.close();
        }
    }
});
```

Where `setReturnValue` is a method belonging to `YourClass` or an instance of it so it will retail your returned value.

Another **way better** approach would be to create a class that extends `Stage` maybe. Also in your `showPrompt` method you will have to block execution using `showAndWait()` or similar.

In conclusion, you can't create your entire `Prompt` from just one method.

Comment: `Where setReturnValue is a static method belonging to YourClass.`Bad advice. `You need to create a class that extends Stage maybe.` Good advice. `...an infinite loop maybe until one of the buttons is pressed.` JavaFX already has APIs for that.

Comment: How do I call this callback?

Comment: I said in my answer that you don't call the *callback*. It is called by the event. You just define the *callback*'s logic without a return. In the end of the answer I offered you a tip of how to get started. Also the bellow answers continue that and show a bit more code.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't**, because by the time you've opened and closed the prompt stage, the main thread will have already passed the `showPrompt` method.

As [Andrei said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424542/how-to-return-result-from-event-handler-in-javafx/23425237#23425237), what you need to do is create your own custom `PromptStage` with a `showPrompt` API that blocks the main thread until the prompt stage is closed.

```
public static String showPrompt(final String title, final String defValue)
{
    // This line will block the main thread
    // See the "showAndWait()" API from JavaFX
    final boolean result = PromptStage.showPrompt("My Prompt Stage", " ");

    // And when the stage is closed, it will carry on to this piece of code
    if (result) 
    {
         return "This is button OK";
    }
    else
    {
         return "This is button CANCEL";
    }
}
```

Or you could even create instances of your `PromptDialog` if you like

```
public static String showPrompt(final String title, final String defValue)
{
    final PromptStage pStage = new PromptStage();

    // This line will block the main thread
    // See the "showAndWait()" API from JavaFX        
    pStage.showAndWait();

    return pStage.getResultAsString();
}
```

There are very many approaches here. To be honest, I won't bother writing the whole class for you. However, do comment if you're stuck.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not understand how it all to use. I have a class Dialog, which contains a static method showPrompt, but what next? What return final boolean result = PromptStage.showPrompt("My Prompt Stage", " ");? Can be an example, if not difficult?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to pass the `showPrompt(...)` method a `StringProperty`, and update the property in your OK button's handler. The caller of `showPrompt` can then create the `StringProperty`, register a listener with it, and observe it. Something like:

```
public String showPrompt(String title, String defValue, final StringProperty result){
    // ...
    final TextField txtPromptValue = new TextField(defValue);
    // ...
    btnOk.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            result.set(txtPromptValue.getText());
            dlgStage.close();
        }
    });    

    // ...
}
```

Then you call the dialog with something like:

```
StringProperty dialogResult = new SimpleStringProperty();
dialogResult.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> obs, String oldValue, String newValue) { 
        // process newValue, the value from the dialog...
    }
});
showPrompt("Dialog Title", "Default value", dialogResult);
```